# How to map Joda Money with org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.joda.PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency type in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, joda-money

Trying this:

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.joda.PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency")
private org.joda.money.Money price;
```

Getting this:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns:domain.ClientOrderItem.price type: org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.joda.PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency
```

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.joda.PersistentMoneyAmount",
parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "currencyCode", value = "USD")})
```

Works nice, but I want to store currency in database and be able to use different currencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a working example from [Jadira Usertype Unit Tests](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/xref-test/org/jadira/usertype/moneyandcurrency/joda/testmodel/MoneyAmountAndCurrencyHolder.html)

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "moneyAmountAndCurrency")
    @TypeDef(name = "testjoda_MoneyAmountWithCurrencyType", typeClass = PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency.class)
    public class MoneyAmountAndCurrencyHolder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1674416082110551506L;

    @Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "MY_CURRENCY"), @Column(name = "MY_AMOUNT") })
    @Type(type = "testjoda_MoneyAmountWithCurrencyType")
    private Money money;
```

Answer (score 4):

### Introduction

This is actually not different from the answer given by [Chris Pheby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533930/chris-pheby). I'm just providing a version of his answer without the `@TypeDef`s, etc, for two scenaria:

1. **Currency** stored as a `CHAR(3)` in MySQL for better readability of data by humans using the [3-**letter** ISO-4217 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes)
2. **Currency** stored as a `SMALLINT` in MySQL for marginally increased efficiency using the [3-**digit** ISO-4217 number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes)

In both cases, the **amount** component of the `Money` field is stored as a `DECIMAL(9,2)` which requires 5 bytes of storage for most RDBMSs. You could, of course, use any other exact datatype in order to avoid possible precision issues that come with `double`/`float`.

### Scenario 1 (3-letter currency representation)

My fictional `Payment` `@Entity` looks like this for scenario (1):

```
package com.fictional;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Columns;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.money.CurrencyUnit;
import org.joda.money.Money;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

/**
 * A fictional payment.
 */
@Entity
public class Payment {

    /**
     * Paid money.
     */
    @Columns(columns = {@Column(name = "paidMoneyCurrency"), @Column(name = "paidMoneyAmount")})
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.joda.PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency")
    private Money paidMoney;


    /**
     * Sample construction of a money object belonging to a payment.
     */
    static public void testPayment()
    {
        Payment p = new Payment();

        p.paidMoney = Money.of(CurrencyUnit.EUR, 1234.56);

        // Hibernate persistence code to insert the new record
    }
}
```

The static method is just an example of instantiating such an object before submitting it to the persistence store.

The corresponding DDL for the database would be this:

```
CREATE TABLE Payment (
    paidMoneyCurrency CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    paidMoneyAmount DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL
);
```

The `INSERT` statement generated by Hibernate looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Payment (paidMoneyCurrency, paidMoneyAmount) VALUES ('EUR', 1234.56);
```

### Scenario 2 (3-digit currency representation)

For scenario (2), you would only have to modify the `@Type` annotation of your `paidMoney` field to read `PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrencyAsInteger` instead of `PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency` (the difference is the **AsInteger** suffix in the class name).

```
    // :
    // :
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.joda.PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrencyAsInteger")
    private Money paidMoney;
    // :
    // :
```

All the remaining code (even instantiation of the `Money` object in the static method) remains the same.

Then you would get the following DDL and corresponding `INSERT` statement generated by Hibernate (`978` is the numeric code for `EUR` automatically calculated for you by joda money)

```
CREATE TABLE Payment (
    paidMoneyCurrency SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    paidMoneyAmount DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Payment (paidMoneyCurrency, paidMoneyAmount) VALUES (978, 1234.56);
```